# [C++]Variables cross .cpp files

Tags: c++, file, variables

This is a silly question with something that must be an easy answer, but after hours of searching I cannot find the answer. What I need to do is have a pair of .cpp files, say main.cpp and help.cpp that have a variable, vars1 that they share and can both change the value and detect when that value has been changed. The way that would make sense to me is that I would simply declare the variable in a class inside a header file and include that header file in both .cpp files, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "variables1.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
variables1 vars1;

do {
    cout << "Welcome\n If you need help, type 'yes' now\n";
    cin.getline(vars1.input, 1024);
    if (strcmp(vars1.input, "yes") == 0 || strcmp(vars1.input, "Yes") == 0){
        vars1.helpvar = true;
        cin.get();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Okay then, glad that you know your way around\n";
    }
    cin.clear();
    cout << "What would you like to do?\n";
    cin.getline(vars1.input, 1024);
    if (strcmp(vars1.input, "logon" ) == 0 ) {

    }
} while (0 == 0);
}
```

help.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "variables1.h"

using namespace std;

int help(){
    variables1 vars1;
    do {
        if (vars1.helpvar == true)
            cout << "detecting";
    } while (0 == 0);
}
```

variables1.h:

```
class variables1
{
public:
    bool helpvar;
    char input[1024];
};
```

Comment: where are you getting the error?

Comment: You might use `extern T variable` or a static member variable to share it.

Comment: First declare the variable in one class in the `private` section with a `public` function that allows the value of the variable to be modified where the instance of this class is used. In this routine you can trigger the process that needs to occur when this value is changed. Remember that you say it is not only important to have the value shared, it is also to trigger another process when the value is indeed changed.

Comment: I would recommend some getting started C++ articles, http://www.cprogramming.com/begin.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is that for the main file and the help.cpp you are creating two different objects and are setting the helpvar variable for each of them separately. What you want is to have a single object that is used by both help.cpp and main to only modify a single instance of the helpvar variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your help function to be along the lines of

```
int help(const variables1& myHelpobject ){
    if (myHelpobject.helpvar == true) {
            cout << "detecting";
    }
}
```

and then call the function in main as:

```
help(vars1)
```

What you were doing before was creating a separate, independent, help object.

Here we are creating the object in main and then passing a reference to it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The technique to use depends on the purpose of your variable.

If it is some sort of **global parameters**, that you have to use throughout all your code,  the simplest is to define it as a global variable:

main file:

```
variables1 vars1;  // outside all functions
int main(){
...
}
```

Either in variables1.h or in the other cpp files using the variable:

```
extern variables1 vars1;  //outside all functions
```

However the code to initialise and maintain these variables in a should also be defined in the class.  The constructor shall for example define the values by default, such as if help is enable or disabled.

If your variables are for **communicating** between different parts of your code, and especially if the main goal of some code is to process the content of these variables, then  should better make this clear by passing the variable as parameter (by reference (&) if the communication is bidirectional, or by value).

Comment: "Simplest" in this case does not equate to "rightest" in the long run.

Comment: I guess a good way to sum it up would be, "least like to get you bashed in a peer code review."

Comment: Peer code review is short run.  Long run is when your app is still running and maintenable in 10 years.  In some cases, it's easier to have some *global* parameters *global*, using all available language construct, instead of poluting function design by forcing everywhere additional parameters not really related to the function itself.  But it's an architectural question to be discussed case by case.

Comment: OK, fine.  It's case-by-case.  Yet the cases where using a global is the right architectural choice decrease exponentially with respect to the size and complexity of the codebase, and for exactly the reason you cite: maintainability.  If only two functions access a given global within a single thread, the semantics are easy to understand. If 10 functions do in 2 threads, it's difficult.  If 200 do in 20 threads, it near impossible.  Its much better to avoid the problem at the project's start by not using globals at all; and yet, that's exactly what you've just taught this new programmer to do.

Comment: I do not want to promote global variables at all cost.  I just say in some cases they are usefull and we should'nt be blinded by dogma.  If writing multithread, the suggestion I made in my answer perfectly allow to manage:  having a proper class and controlling access to the variables, would permit to built in some mutex access controls, or define atomics<> without changing the desing of the rest of the project.

Comment: I suppose we could call everything "dogma," disregard decades of accumulated wisdom, and say that any mechanism is fine so long as you put a lock around it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues with the code as posted:

**`int help()` is never run**

Something needs to call this function for it to run. There isn't anything doing that so regardless of the value of `vars1.helpvar` you are never going to see `"detecting"` output.

Consider adding a help.hpp with the definition of the function and call the function from `main`.

**`vars1.helpvar` is not shared between main and `int help()`**

Currently you have two instances of `variables1` and `helpvar` is a member variable so each instance has a separate copy.

You could either:

1. Make `helpvar` a static member of `variables1`
2. Share once instance of `variables1` between both `main` and `help`.

The use of static variables is more likely give design problem later so I'd favour option 2.